# How can I use 신스틸 하다?

Tags: vocabulary

I came across the verb '신스틸 하다', which seems to be derived from the English 'scene-stealing'.

Is this something that can be used in a metaphorical way about everyday life, or does it only apply to people taking part in a performance?

Can 신스틸 be used as a noun on its own?

Comment: Well, frankly that sounds too much like 보그체 https://namu.wiki/w/%EB%B3%B4%EA%B7%B8%EC%B2%B4 to me, but maybe I'm just an old fart. (I've been living outside Korea for ~7 years now, so I can't be an authority on recently popular expressions...)

Answer (score 1):

1) 신스틸하다 = 간지 폭풍 = 미친 존재감 = To dominate a performance
through charisma, humour or powerful acting

2) 신스틸 = noun

3) I do not know whether Koreans use this in normal life. But if I try :

오늘 미팅 어땠냐 ? How was today's discussion ?

내가 신스틸했어. I made an excellent presentation (=I
 persuaded opponents) or I am totally stupid.